# Changing the Keymap in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-10.10, keyboard-layout, keymap

Is it possible, using Ubuntu Linux, to change the meanings of the keyboards keys? I needed the right shift key to act as the home key and the right ctrl key to act as the end key. How to do this system wide for every installed application?

Comment: it's about this device http://www.notebooksbilliger.de/netbooks/asus+netbooks/asus+eee+pc+x101+red013g with Intel Meego replaced by Ubuntu Linux

Comment: Check this [AskUbuntu question](http://askubuntu.com/q/24916/1182)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sathya's comment solved the problem completely.

Sathya mentioned a Link on AskUbuntu solving the same problem.

The link is https://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys